# .Net 4.0, New methods in existing classes

Tags: .net-4.0

Is there a blog or MSDN article, which lists all the new methods which are added in .Net 4.0 in existing classes? I could not find any.

Two which I found on blogs till now:

```
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace
Enum.HasFlag
```

Are there more such methods added which anybody found? If yes, please share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the blog of the .NET BCL (base class library) team, there is a list of changes, although it is for .NET 4 Beta 1 and 2:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2009/05/22/what-s-new-in-the-bcl-in-net-4-beta-1-justin-van-patten.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2009/10/21/what-s-new-in-the-bcl-in-net-4-beta-2-justin-van-patten.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Theres a few new ones on the page class:

```
Page.MetaDescription = "";
Page.MetaKeywords = "";
```

Plus a new 301 method:

```
Response.RedirectPermanent("~/page.aspx");
```

I guess this isn't really the best way to approach it as many of the new features wouldn't make much sense without being put into context.

This document highlights most of the new features if you want to get up to speed on .net 4:

- [ASP.NET 4 and Visual Studio 2010 Web Development Overview](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/whitepapers/aspnet4/)

Comment: I know most of the new features and instead, using them in my projects which I am shifting to 4.0. But I just wanted to know new convenience methods added to old classes for simplifying common tasks. Thanks though. The page you linked is quite helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

This link shows the updated list, which gammelgul posted, for RTM:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=VS.100).aspx